# npm does not support Node.js v13.14.0

Tags: node.js

Hello hope you are well!

I try to install a project react in my pc so I started to install  npx create-next-app hulu-2-yt.
but me display this error in my cmd.
npm does not support Node.js v13.14.0

You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we can't make any promises that npm will work  with version.

I try to make upgrade for Last version of the nodejs but I  have windows 7 and  said me that can not support for windows 7.

Do you have any solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should upgrade `node` manualy all you have to do uninstall the old `node` version and watch this video [Installing Latest Node and React In windows 7 or Low End PC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-C829JGEZs) is helped me lot to resolve the problem i hope it working for you as well.

Comment: thanks for your answer I follows tutorial that you have send me open cmd

Comment: thanks for your answer I followed  tutorial that you have send me open cmd  writen:  node -v node -v v16.14.0   npm -v npm -v 8.3.1.        https://i.postimg.cc/qq6ZXcP2/error-vue.png

Comment: the problem isn't  with nodejs you have to go to the vue js documentation and figure out how is it install